# Why does my NSMenuItem cause a beep

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsmenu

I'm working on a Cocoa app, and I've got an NSMenuItem that causes a beep, like it's not allowed. Doesn't matter if I invoke it from the keyboard shortcut or by using the mouse. The weird thing is, the command actually works fine. It just beeps as well.

Comment: Search, if the NSBeep()-command is used somewhere...

Comment: No NSBeep() in my project anywhere.

Comment: Okay, that sounds difficult to find. Because a system-Beep regularly is called, when the system is asked to do something, that is not correct/possible. So I would recommend, to disable commands - by commenting them out - in the methods and if the beep disappears, activate the commands method by method from the beginning of the serie. If you don't know how the methods are called, use NSLOG() with messages, which you can see in the log window. If it all doesn't help, replace the NSMenu in IB by a new one and use "Clean all targets" in XCode and then build again.